# Creating clean, inheritable objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, underscore.js, prototype

I'm working with a fairly large JavaScript project and trying to refactor it to persuade it to behave in more of a JavaScripty way. One thing I really want to bring in is to make inheritance available as this is a very good fit for much of the work I am doing, but it seems a little hard to use prototypes and inheritance in a way that is easy to read and follow without dissolving into JavaScript jam.

I have got to something like this:

```
MyMammal = function( name ) {
    if ( 0 < arguments.length )
    {
       this.init(name);
    }
}
MyMammal.prototype=  {
    init: function( name ) {
        this.name= name;
    },

    getName: function() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Then for classes that derive from `MyMammal`I work this way:

```
MyDog = function( name, breed ) {
    if ( 0 < arguments.length ) 
    {
        this.init( name, breed );
    }
}
MyDog.prototype = Object.create( MyMammal.prototype );

_.extend( MyDog.prototype, {
    init: function( name, breed )
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.breed = breed;
    },

    getBreed: function() 
    {
        return this.breed;
    }
});
```

Now this works in so far as I get the outcomes I expect from method calls but JavaScript doesn't seem to know that `MyMammal` is the prototype of `MyDog` if I try to use `isPrototypeOf` although it does recognise that an instance of `MyDog` is an `instanceof MyMammal`.

As I understand it, in addition to the conventional advantages of being able to create subclasses easily, JavaScript prototypes also share functions, so using them well should be more memory efficient. My question is firstly whether this model will be able to take advantage of that ( I can't see why it wouldn't, but that's why I'm asking ) and secondly whether there are any major downsides to using this type of structure for code for a large JS application?  I'm trying to work in an idiomatic JavaScript way and I'm not too worried about keeping my local variables secret.

Comment: Nice code, where does _.extend came from. IE11 doesn't support this

Comment: @Mouser `_` is underscore or lodash library

Comment: @Mouser that is part of Underscore ( http://underscorejs.org/#extend ) which is one of the libraries that since I started using it I can't live without...

Comment: @glenatron ok!. I started to fiddle around with your code. `MyMammal.prototype.isPrototypeOf([instance])` returns true.

Comment: @MyMouser, ah, that is useful to know. I probably missed the "prototype" step there.

Comment: You now have inner functions in your classes. If you create outer functions and reference them it is more efficient when creating multiple instances.

Comment: @Mouser this is exactly what I need to know- maybe you could show why I have inner functions rather than prototype level functions/how I can adjust it and put that in an answer?

Answer (score 1):

This for example:

```
MyMammal = function( name ) {
    if ( 0 < arguments.length )
    {
       this.init(name);
    }
}
MyMammal.prototype=  {
    init: function( name ) {
        this.name= name;
    },

    getName: retrieveNameOfMammal}; //here is where the fun happens

function retrieveNameOfMammal()
{
    return this.name;
}

MyDog = function( name, breed ) {
     MyMammal.apply(this, name); //this will apply all properties and functions from MyMammal, so you do not have to recreate this.init every time.
 }
```

Comment: Is this not what is happening by adding them to the prototype? My understanding was that the prototype functions are shared across instances, but the function member functions are not. So if I had a function in `MyMammal` that would be per-instance, but in `MyMammal.prototype` all `MyMammal` instances would partake of it?

Comment: True, `getName` is available for every instance and for every instance the same and only created once. Still this way delivers more readable code :-)